# Converting TPM data to read counts for Seurat

Tags: r, seurat

I would like to do an analysis in R with Seurat, but for this I need a count matrix with read counts. However, the data I would like to use is provided in [TPM](http://www.arrayserver.com/wiki/index.php?title=TPM), which is not ideal for using as input since I would like to compare with other analyses that used read counts.

**Does anyone know a way to convert the TPM data to read counts?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question would have higher chance of being answered if you added some code examples. Something like I have code that looks like this (some lines of data from TPM) I would like to transform it into a read.counts compatible format (show example of what you think the data should look like, or failing that show the data you would like to compare it with that is in read.counts format)

Comment: what is TPM? Looking at the package, seems like better suited for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You would need total counts and gene (or transcript) lengths to an
approximation of that conversion. See https://support.bioconductor.org/p/91218/
for the reverse operation.

From that link:

You can create a TPM matrix by dividing each column of the counts matrix by
some estimate of the gene length (again this is not ideal for the reasons stated above).

```
x <- counts.mat / gene.length
```

Then with this matrix x, you do the following:

```
tpm.mat <- t( t(x) * 1e6 / colSums(x) )
```

*Such that the columns sum to 1 million.*

`colSums(x)` would be the counts per sample aligned to the genes in the TPM
matrix, and `gene.length` would depend on the gene model used for read
summarization.

So you may be out of luck, and would probably be better off using something
like [salmon](https://combine-lab.github.io/salmon/) or
[kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/) anyway to get the count
matrix from the fastq files, if those are available, based on the gene or
transcript model that you used in the data you want to compare it to.

If you have no other option than to use the TPM data (not really recommended),
Seurat can work with that as well - see
https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/171.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did use the TPM data now, and it seemingly worked okay.

Comment: they dropped that feature by now, unfortunately